# An issue where memory peaks abnormally and then normalizes again

Tags: performance, memory, server, window, disk

There is an issue where an application running on a Windows server normally uses only about 50% of the memory, but at some point, the memory reaches 90% and the application does not function properly.

It is a search service that periodically imports data into the DB and is also requested by customers. When checking the memory usage with a monitoring tool, no memory leaks were found, but the memory suddenly peaks at irregular intervals and does not function properly for a while. Yes, there is an issue that normalizes after a certain period of time.

The server specifications are about 80GB of memory, but about 50G is allocated to the application.

It's not a memory leak, but I'm curious as to why the memory suddenly fills up.

I tried increasing the memory and reducing the amount of metadata retrieved from the DB, but the same issue occurred.
I am using an HDD and am planning to change to an SSD, but I am asking a question because it is difficult to confirm whether the disk is the problem.